# Как рандомно выбрать объект и изменить значение?

Tags: java

У меня есть:

```
    private List<Products> boughtProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

в котором есть объекты:

```
Products[] products = {
        Products.makeProduct(TypeOfProduct.DRIED_FRUITS,20,13,Quality.NORMAL),
        Products.makeProduct(TypeOfProduct.MEAT,40,7,Quality.NORMAL),
        Products.makeProduct(TypeOfProduct.GRAIN,50,15,Quality.NORMAL),
        Products.makeProduct(TypeOfProduct.FLOUR,50,43,Quality.NORMAL),
        Products.makeProduct(TypeOfProduct.PAINT,10,11,Quality.NORMAL),
};
```

**Вопрос:** Как я могу выбрать случайно один из объектов List и изменить ее значение,а также изменить значение всех объектов в List?

Comment: генерируйте рандом в диапазоне 0-размер коллекции, вот вам рандомный индекс.

Comment: Stream API, `findAny()` + `forEach`